# Why am I getting a certificate validation error for what seems to be a valid certificate?

Tags: python, docker, ssl, python-requests

I am running a Docker daemon protected with a locally generated ssl certificate. Docker connects to the server without a problem. When I try to connect using the `requests` module, I get a validation error:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('https://docker.local:2376')                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE] sslv3 alert bad certificate (_ssl.c:2627)
```

The error doesn't provide much in the way of detail other than "bad certificate".

Just to be sure, I tried pointing `requests` explicitly at the same CA
file that docker is using, but I get the same error:

```
>>> import requests
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.verify = '/home/buzzword/.docker/ca.pem'
>>> s.get('https://docker.local:2376')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE] sslv3 alert bad certificate (_ssl.c:2627)
```

If I grab the certificate using `openssl`, I also see some errors:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect docker.local:2376 > docker.crt
depth=1 ...
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = docker.local
verify return:1
140520382674752:error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate:ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1543:SSL alert number 42
```

But if I explicitly validate the certificate using the `openssl verify` command it returns successfully:

```
$ openssl verify docker.crt
docker.crt: OK
```

Why are `docker` and `openssl verify` happy, but `requests` and
`openssl s_client` are not?

---

This is what `openssl x509 ...` says about the certificate:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 8238984585537887426 (0x7256c0d41ae79cc2)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = XX, L = YY, O = My Organization, OU = Certificate Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan 30 21:57:00 2021 GMT
            Not After : Jan  9 13:05:00 2030 GMT
        Subject: CN = docker.local
        [...]
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                56:AC:73:3C:92:87:8F:F2:30:F6:6A:10:14:3E:8B:7F:B7:CD:0C:AD
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Key Agreement
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:docker.local
            Netscape Cert Type: 
                SSL Server
            Netscape Comment: 
                xca certificate
```

The certificate for the signing authority is available in
`/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt` and looks like this:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 5876977844214468982 (0x518f3836353e9176)
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = XX, L = YY, O = My Organization, OU = Certificate Authority
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan  9 13:05:00 2020 GMT
            Not After : Jan  9 13:05:00 2030 GMT
        Subject: C = US, ST = XX, L = YY, O = My Organization, OU = Certificate Authority
        [...]
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                3F:62:D2:9A:65:37:91:E1:42:79:16:28:E7:A6:89:45:C5:01:4D:EB
            X509v3 Key Usage: 
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            Netscape Cert Type: 
                SSL CA, S/MIME CA, Object Signing CA
            Netscape Comment: 
                xca certificate
```

Comment: Does the certificate contain full chain? Also, according the [documentation](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) environment variable `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` should be set.

Comment: If it’s a self-signed certificate, it will always fail validation. You can add a parameter `verify=False` to your `requests.get` call to not validate. https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Comment: It is not a self signed certificate (it is signed by a local certificate authority, whose ca certificate is installed in the system certificate bundle and also in `~/.docker/ca.pem`). Demonstrably, it validates just fine when using the `docker` client.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I believe setting `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` should have the same effect as explicitly setting the `verify` attribute of the `session` object to a certificate bundle. I tried when setting `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` and it fails the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "bad certificate" error means that your server is expecting your client to authenticate with its own certificate, but when calling `requests.get` you're not providing one. You want something like:

```
>>> requests.get(
... 'https://docker.local:2376',
... cert=['/home/buzzword/.docker/cert.pem', '/home/buzzword/.docker/key.pem']
... )
```

(assuming that you have `cert.pem` and `key.pem` in your `~/.docker`
directory)

Comment: Thanks, that was it.